# Javascript max() function for 3 numbers

Tags: javascript, math, max

I need to find the highest number from 3 different numbers. The only thing I've found is max() but you can only use 2 numbers.

Whats the best way?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function can accept any arbitrary number of arguments:

Syntax:

```
Math.max([value1[,value2[, ...]]])
```

Usage:

```
var max = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
```

For example:

```
console.log(Math.max(1,2,3,4,5,6)); //  6
```

You could even use it to get the maximum value of an array of numbers with the help of [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```js
function maxOfArray(array) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
}


let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(maxOfArray(array)); // 6
```

If you can target ES6 (ES2015), you can also use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let max = Math.max(...array);
console.log(max); // 6
```

Comment: +1 I don't know why this hasn't been picked up on before and it's by far the simplest solution. If you want it to work with an array just use Math.max.apply(Math, array)

Comment: Google seems to love SO.  I was googling 'javascript max' 45 minutes after the question was first posted, and found this answer on the first page :-)

Answer (score 22):

In almost any language, one can use max twice:

```
Math.max(num1, Math.max(num2, num3))
```

As @CMS points out, JavaScript specifically allows an arbitrary number of parameters to Math.max:

```
Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
```

Comment: Math.max can accept any arbitrary number of arguments, see my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418569/javascript-max-function-for-3-numbers/1418646#1418646

Comment: @CMS: +1 Very cool, I learned something.  I'm not aware of another mainstream language that does that, though in principal any language that can accept a variable number of function arguments could.

Comment: 17 people liked the answer but 2 downvoted.  Unfortunately neither left a reason.  Would be nice to understand the downvotes so that we all can learn...

Answer (score 2):

Push your values into an array `arr` and use `Math.min.apply(null, arr)` or `Math.max.apply(null, arr)` for maximum and minimum values respectively:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(value1);
arr.push(value2);
arr.push(value3);

var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using with the new spread operator

```
var num = [23,34,56,72,1,22]; 
Math.max(...num)
```

[for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Badacadabra The value of this answer you get to write a bit less code and get to use "spread operator"
Now u should  upvote I hope

Answer (score 0):

let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let largest = 0;
for(let i = 0; i<=largest; i++){
(largest<array[i]? largest = array[i]:0)
}
console.log(largest);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var numbers = [2,3,1];
 numbers.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
 console.log("max number is", numbers[0]); // max number is 3
```