# jquery to make 2 column height equal only works when alert()

Tags: jquery, css, html

hey guys hope you can help me out,

I am having a weird problem. I am working on a web page that has two floating divs (among many other things). To make the floating divs of equal height, I added the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   alert($('#body-left').height());
    if($('#body-left').height()>$('#sidebar').height()){
     $('#sidebar').height($('#body-left').height());

    }
    else{

    $('#body-left').height($('#sidebar').height());

    }

});
```

see the line  "alert($('#body-left').height());", when I remove that line, it stops working :/. I.e :

this is what happens when I dont add the alert() line:
[image]

and this is what happens when I do add the alert line

[image]

any ideas why this is happening? :/

---

sorry for the late reply guys, but I got it working using

```
if($('#body-left').height()>$('#sidebar').height()){
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('#sidebar').height($('#body-left').height());
    },100);

}
else{
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#body-left').height($('#sidebar').height());
    },100);
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: can I see the relevant HTML and CSS for these elements please?

Comment: Have you considered using `display: table-cell` instead of `float: left` for your divs? Doing so will automatically make them the same height (but won't work in IE7).

Comment: @blaze, yup thats why I diddnt use table-cell;

Comment: I prefer to use `display: table-cell` when appropriate and use an IE7-only stylesheet to add `float: left`. The layout isn't as clean, but I figure that's what they deserve for not upgrading. :-P

Comment: You can also use `Math.max` to simplify your code: `maxheight = Math.max($('#body-left').height(), $('#sidebar').height());` -- and then set the height of both elements to `maxheight`.

Comment: i think it is better to use outerHeight instead of height!

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net so we can test it

Comment: ok sorry for the late reply, I got it to work using the code updated above

Comment: What does the alert tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1418569/901048) as a basis, you can quickly take the max height of any number of elements. If you gave them all the class `equalheight`, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxheight = $.map($('.equalheight'), function(val, i) {
        return $(val).height();
    }).max();
    $('.equalheight').height(maxheight);
});

Array.prototype.max = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, this);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NR9TZ/

Answer (score 1):

If you want equal heights...try this plugin:

```
$.fn.setMinHeight = function(setCount) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i+=setCount) {
    var curSet = this.slice(i, i+setCount), 
        height = 0;
    curSet.each(function() { height = Math.max(height, $(this).height()); })
          .css('height', height);
  }
  return this;
};
```

Copy and paste the above code into a JS file and link to it. Then call it like so...

```
$(".theItems").setMinHeight(2); // Pass in number of items to include.
```

Hope this helps.

Michael.