# Finding largest integer in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How might I find the largest number contained in a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379553/how-might-i-find-the-largest-number-contained-in-a-javascript-array)

I am having trouble getting this code to work. I have been at it for a while trying to figure it out. When I look at the console it just displays 0. What did I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var array = [3 , 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest= 0;

for (i=0; i<=largest;i++){
    if (array>largest) {
        var largest=array[i];
    }
}

console.log(largest);
```

Comment: The largest number of an empty array should be `-Infinity`.

Comment: Simplest Way:

var nums = [1,4,5,3,1,4,7,8,6,2,1,4];
nums.sort();
nums.reverse();
alert(nums[0]);

Comment: const array1 = [1, 3, 2];

console.log(Math.max(...array1));
// expected output: 3

Comment: @SiddharthaMahato That sorts them lexicographically, not numerically. You need to pass a numerical comparison function to `.sort()`. `(a, b) => a - b` for ascending or `(a, b) => b - a` for descending (which would also let you drop the `.reverse()`).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = 0;

for (let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}

console.log(largest);
```

Comment: Don't redeclare largest in the if statement. You've already declared the var in the opening under array.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer since there are more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: This fails when the first array item is `0` or `negative`. It also fails if the array starts with two `1`s or three `2`s or so on.

Comment: I am sure @Yamaha32088 made a mistake in the for loop. It should be be i <= array.length instead of i < largest. The condition will only pass for the first round of loop.

Comment: This is not the solution now sure why there is a tick mark on solution

This will give array out of bound error.
beacuse of  (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) -> this will over run the limit of length.

var array = [3 , 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
let largest= 0;

function largestFunction() {

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (largest < arr[i] ) {
        largest = arr[i];
    }
}
return largest; 
}

console.log(largestFunction);

Comment: the for loops needs to run while `i<array.length`, not `i<largest`

Answer (score 40):

```js
var arr = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = arr[0];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > largest ) {
    largest = arr[i];
  }
}
console.log(largest);
```

- You need to define `i` or else it become a global variable.
- Don't redefine largest in the loop.
- Since you're looping through the array, use `i < array.length` instead of `i <= largest`.
- Since you're comparing each of the items in the array to `largest`, use `if(largest < array[i])` instead of `if(array > largest)`
- You should set largest equal to the first element in the array because what if all the numbers are negative?
- `array` is a bad variable name because it's too similar to `Array` (the array constructor). Try `arr` instead.

One liner:

`var largest = Math.max.apply(0, array);`

More info here: [Javascript max() function for 3 numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418569/javascript-max-function-for-3-numbers)

Comment: Unfortunately Math.max is out as an option for very large arrays. In the testing I'm doing right now, the max array length that Math.max can handle is 123679 elements. This probably changes on javascript platform, but it illustrates that Math.max is *almost* as fast as straight iteration, but isn't quite as fast and fails for very large arrays.

Comment: @Geuis I didn't know that, but that seems more like a memory issue to me. It might because of the way `apply` is implemented. What platform are you testing on? Do you have a link to your test?

Comment: Here's a jsperf I modified with additional test cases. http://jsperf.com/array-sorting-javascript-stack/2 Note that Math.max appears slightly faster in Firefox, but not significantly faster. Appears a good old loop and if test is fastest. I added checks for while negation, and to see if ternary comparisons might be faster. They aren't.

Comment: This will give array out of bound error.for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (largest < arr[i] ) {
        largest = arr[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);

Answer (score 23):

Just one line :)

```
var array = [3 , 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32],
    largest = array.sort((a,b)=>a-b).reverse()[0];
```

or even better

```
...
    largest = array.sort((a,b)=>a-b)[array.length - 1];
```

UPD, all code above is sucks when you add for example 9 in array my guess because by default numbers treated as strings in sort, there is better version

```
var array = [3 , 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32, 9], largest;
array.sort(function(a, b) {
   largest = a > b ? a: b;
});
```

although in performance wise `forEach` loop suggested in comments are better
http://jsperf.com/array-sorting-javascript-stack

UPD2, okay, code above has some bad parts in it, so will not work as expected. Another try:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
largest = array[array.length - 1];
```

Comment: Cool, but sorting is slower.

Comment: @LarryBattle compare with what? here is jsperf http://jsperf.com/array-sorting-javascript-stack, the only drowback here is if you have null defined elements, but need to check though

Comment: This is a VERY inefficient method. js array sorts are rather slow. http://jsfiddle.net/ychWw/ In my simple testing, method1 completes in around 50ms, while your method takes 5 seconds.

Comment: @Geuis, yea foreach cool) what about support? and I would choose less code instead of speed in 70% otherwise will never use jQuery:)

Comment: Worse than being slow, it's wrong.  `sort` converts elements to strings first.  The sorted output becomes: `[2, 3, 32, 32, 5, 56, 6, 89]` - you got lucky for this set but add a `9` in there and it will be calculated as the "largest".

Comment: @Dennis, updated, though not such fast now

Comment: @dmi3y You're calling `sort` but you aren't actually sorting the array and providing the callback defeats the purpose you laid out for even using `sort` in the first place (multiple lines).  Also, since you are only writing to `largest`, never actually reading it, you can't be checking for the largest value either.  If you swap 32 and 89 you'll get the wrong answer, again.

Comment: @Dennis, good one, updated

Comment: Actually reduce is both looking good and runs fast:

```
   array.reduce((item, acc) => item > acc ? item : acc, array[0])
```

You can check here: https://jsperf.com/array-sorting-javascript-stack/4

Answer (score 4):

You have a few small mistakes.  First:

```
if (array > largest) {
```

It should instead be:

```
if (array[i] > largest) {
```

Second:

```
for (i = 0; i <= largest; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = [3 , 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest= array[0];

for (i=0; i<=largest;i++){
    if (array[i]>largest) {
        largest=array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is re-declaring `largest` inside the loop instead of assigning it

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues in your code.  First, `array>largest` should be `array[i]>largest`.  Second, you are declaring a new largest variable inside the `if` which isn't the same as the one outside.  Remove `var` from the assignment of the new largest value.

Comment: Math.max(...array)