# How to find biggest variable using while loop?

Tags: java

I have defined 16 variables and assigned them with different kind of values.

```
int block0 = 5;
int block1 = 6;
int block2 = 8;
int block3 = 25;
int block4 = 8;
int block5 = 23;
int block6 = 2;
int block7 = 1;
int block8 = 6;
int block9 = 4;
int block10 = 5;
int block11 = 7;
int block12 = 15;
int block13 = 4;
int block14 = 5;
int block15 = 8;
```

How can i find the biggest variable among all using while or for loop?

Comment: arrays are your friend

Comment: Im assuming (from the `int`) that that's Java and not JavaScript, right?

Comment: Use an array. Question answered already, check here for code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794225/finding-largest-integer-in-array-javascript

Comment: [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)

Comment: This is not JavaScript, this is Java. They are not the same thing. Anyways, store them in some array, sort it largest to smallest, and get the first item.

Comment: yes, its blueJ but its java so I could customize the answer.

Comment: NO, I cannot use arrays. I was told to not to use arrays..

Comment: What were you told to use? Why don't you use that.

Comment: OK, make them fields in an object and use reflections.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Sorting is not that optimal when you only want to find the max.

Comment: @MichaelGamage I don't belileve you.  Can you post the text of your assignment.(maybe they want you to use a linked list or something)

Comment: with int type, you only can use a while loop if you declare one array or List, or other think you know less than one variable for each value.

Comment: @anana I never said it was optimal. It was a suggestion.

Comment: @SamIam - I did post the assignment question and end up losing my whole reputation.. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599079/solve-without-using-arrays?noredirect=1

Comment: @MichaelGamage The reason I read your assignment is because I wanted to see if it actually told you to not use arrays(and it didn't)

Comment: @MichaelGamage And posting your assignment's text per-se isn't what made you lose rep, It was that you didn't do much other than ask us to solve your assignment. What you want to do is try to present it as though you're not asking for us to do your work.  Make it more focused on how can sense be made of this assignment if you can't use arrays.

Comment: @MichaelGamage and the problem is, even with the assignment definition in that question, I still don't have proper context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you have to make them into an array

```
int[] intArr = new int[16];

int[0] = 5;
int[1] = 6;
...
```

and then you can iterate

```
int max = 0;
int maxIndex = 0;

for(int i=0; i<intArr.length; i++)
{
    if(max < intArr[i])
        maxIndex = i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You **should**, but if you **can't** use arrays, you can use `Math.max()`, like this **beautiful** code:

```
int max = Math.max(block0, Math.max(block1, Math.max(block2, Math.max(block3, Math.max(block4, Math.max(block5, Math.max(block6, Math.max(block7, Math.max(block8, Math.max(block9, Math.max(block10, Math.max(block11, Math.max(block12, Math.max(block13, Math.max(block14, block15)))))))))))))));
```

Unless they are fields in a class, you **cannot iterate** (using a `for` or `while`, as you say) through those variables (local variables). You only option other than `Math.max()` is a huge `if` statement. Compared to it, though, `Math.max()` looks pretty.

Answer (score 2):

If you really can't use arrays, make your own method:

```
public static int maxValue(int... values) {
        int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for(int x : values)
            maximum = (x > maximum) ? x : maximum;

        return maximum;
    }
```

That way you can call it with multiple arguments, eg. by saying

```
int max = maxValue(block0, block1, /*etc*/, block15);
```

@acdcjunior 's solution with multiple Math.max methods works of course, too.

Answer (score 0):

it's rather easy..

Just do a simple sort..

```
function findlarge()
{
   var largest = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
   {
     largest = ((block+i) > block+(i+1)) ? block+i : block+i+1; 
   }
   return largest;
}
```

please note you'd need to address the incorrect variable names I used..but this is how I'd sort out the largest..

Good luck :)

Comment: You can't do what you seem to think you can do.  If `i` is 1, `block+i` just adds 1 to `block`, it does not get you the value of `block1`.

Comment: @Dory In java you can write this code and you will not have an error, but it will not produce what you think

Comment: Guys I know this..The tag also said javascript :) and besides please see the note I had bellow..I was just suggesting the logic, not more than that.

Comment: But you can't "suggest the logic" if that involves tools that do not exist in the entourage of the solution (as you cannot say "just use eval()"). Now that it is clear that it is only Java related, you should remove this answer.