# JavaScript: greatest value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

The function only reurn the greatest number if it is at **first** *(arr[0])*, or **last index** *(arr[arr.length-1])* of the array. How do I fix the logical error?

```js
function isGreater(arr) {
 let a = arr[0];
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var isGreat = (a < arr[i]) ? arr[i] : a;
 }
 return isGreat;
}
console.log(isGreater([7, 9, 10000, 11, 25, 20]));
// output=> 20, expected output 10000
console.log(isGreater([7, 11, 25, 2]));
// output=> 7, expected output 25
```

Comment: Try `Math.max.apply(null, [7, 9, 10000, 11, 25, 20])`.

Comment: `Math.max.apply(null, [7, 9, 10000, 11, 25, 20])` But in any case, you need to have a variable, set to 0 before the loop, that is set to the larger of itself or the current array element in each loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding largest integer in an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794225/finding-largest-integer-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I think it's cleaner to use the spread operator than `Function.prototype.apply`. In this case, `Math.max(...[7, 9, 10000, 11, 25, 20])`

Ultimately, performance varies between browsers and both can cause a stack overflow with large arrays, so it's really a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the first value of the array as actually greatest value and start the loop from index `1`. No need for `a`, another reference to the array.

Inside the loop check if `isGreat` is smaller than the actual value value and update `isGreat`.

The check prevents to assign a superfluous assignment of the old and new greatest value.

```js
function isGreater(arr) {
    let isGreat = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (isGreat < arr[i]) {
            isGreat = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return isGreat;
}

console.log(isGreater([7, 9, 10000, 11, 25, 20])); // 10000
console.log(isGreater([7, 11, 25, 2]));            //    25
```

Answer (score 4):

The logic error is that you're assigning either `arr[i]` or `a` to `isGreat`, but never comparing `isGreat` to `arr[i]`.

Just reuse `a` rather than using `isGreat`:

```js
function isGreater(arr) {
    let a = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        a = a < arr[i] ? arr[i] : a;
    }
    return a;
}
console.log(isGreater([7, 9, 10000, 11, 25, 20]));
console.log(isGreater([7, 11, 25, 2]));
```

Note that I updated that to skip the first index in the loop, since `a` already contains that value.

This line:

```
a = a < arr[i] ? arr[i] : a;
```

could be this if you prefer:

```
if (a < arr[i]) {
    a = arr[i];
}
```

---

I assume this is an exercise. If not, you can get your result more directly like this:

```
// ES2015+
function isGreater(arr) {
    return Math.max(...arr);
}
```

or this:

```
// ES5 and earlier
function isGreater(arr) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
function fun(){
   let arr = [7, 9, 10000, 11, 25, 20];
 let a = arr[0];
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  a = (a < arr[i]) ? arr[i] : a;
 }
 return a; //Returns 10000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you defined `isGreat` inside of a loops, so it will be redefined every iteration. Try this:

```js
function isGreater(arr){
       let greatest = arr[0];
       for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
          if(arr[i] > greatest){
            greatest = arr[i];
          }
       }
       return greatest;
}
    
console.log(isGreater([0, 4, 6, 1, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are finding the greatest, you should try to compare current value with **current greatest value** so the greatest one will change across the iteration.

this is the example

```
function isGreater(arr) {
  let greatest = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    greatest = greatest < arr[i] ? arr[i] : greatest;
  }
  return greatest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although, you may already have better answers, I did it like this:

```
const isGreater = arr => {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
};
```

This just sorts the array in a descending order, and returns the first element of the newly ordered array.